# Add some values before/to character array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, println, type-2-dimension

I am new to arrays in java.
If I wanted to show this:

```
    0 ....
    1 ....
    2 ....    
    3 .... 
    4 ....
```

where:

```
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....     is a 2-d char array called char[][] squares.
```

How do I add the numbers before the squares array?

And, if I choose one number, say, 3, and wanted to add ">" right next to 3, how should I do that? So, what I want is:

```
    0 ....
    1 ....
    2 ....    
    3>.... 
    4 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int y = 0; y< array.lenght;y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x< array[y].lenght;x++) {
        System.out.println(array[y][x]);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void print_array(char[][] squares, int selectedIndex){
    for(int i =0;i<squares.length;i++){
        System.out.print(i);
        if(i == selectedIndex){
            System.out.print(">");
        }
        for(int j = 0;j<squares[i].length;j++){
            System.out.print(squares[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this kind of questions are allowed, but here is the answer. 
let us assume you have chars[m][n] array.
and your want to print > before x line

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
      String s = i+"";
      if(i == x) s = s + ">";
      else       s = s+ " ";
      s = s + new String(chars[i])
      System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather cryptic but I'll give it a shot:

```
class Whatever {

public static void Main(String[] args) {

char[][] squares = new char[5][2];

/*
Here goes your code to assign values to the array
*/

for(int i:=0, i<5; ++i) {
   System.out.println(i);
   if (i==3) {
      System.out.print("> ");
   } else {
      System.out.print("  ")
   }
   for(j:=0; j<2; ++j) {
      System.out.println(aquares[i][j]);
   }
}
}
```